# problem in adjusting background image in css

Tags: html, css

I'm a beginner in html, css and stuck in a problem where I am trying to adjust a background image according to screen size but can't.

You can see that the full picture is not adjusted according to screen size and looks like after a certain portin a the picture started again. I don't know what is the problem and how to tackle it .

html

[image: my html code]

CSS

[image: my css]

My website

[image: my website]

the picture  I want as my background

[image]

Comment: You need to show us your CSS. And please put the code into the question and not as an image. You may need to read up about aspect ratios.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Also check out background repeat

Comment: `background-size: cover`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't add no-repeat in css. So your background image repeats.
Try this:

```
background: url(paste here your link) no-repeat;
```

You can also visit w3schools and read about backgrounds.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Next time please paste your code, not screens.